# Ajax request what?

Tags: ajax

So I have a stupid question about this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: `URL`,
            data: DO STUFF WITH WHAT I GOT FROM THE REQUEST???,
        });
```

In ajax, when I make a get request from a URL, with the `data:` parameter am I giving a response that is `data` or is `data` the data I received from the request?

Comment: The `data` property in your code is the data you send to the server.

Comment: So how do I mess with the data I got from the GET? This confuses me no matter how much I read the documentation.

Comment: You provide a callback to handle the asynchronous response.  Take a look at the `.done()` callback in the examples: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Might you have an example I could see of this or something that is not documentation? The documentation has less than informative examples that don't really help a new person at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something with the data in the success part of the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'json',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});
```

In this case, a potential success callback would look like this:

```
function success(data) {
  // do something with data, which is an object
}
```

or if there is no data to send:

```
function testAjax(handleData) {
  $.ajax({
    url:"getvalue.php",  
    success:function(data) {
      handleData(data); 
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: So really I don't even need `data:` in the request if all I want to do is take the data that I received from the server when I made the request. I just do it all in `success(data received) = > {do stuff},`

Comment: Yes if you are not sending anything. See my updated answer. The data parameter of the callback function is what is returned from the ajax call.

Comment: I ended up using this and it works like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The main thing to understand here is that any AJAX call (any web request really) has two components:  A request and a response.  The actual `$.ajax()` function call is sending the request, and a callback function is provided to handle the response.

To illustrate:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", // request type
    url: "http://www.example.com/someResource", // destination URL
    data: { name: "David", location: "Boston" } // data to send
});
```

This would make a GET request to the specified URL, sending it the specified data.  The response in this case is ignored, since no callback is provided.  But you can provide one:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.example.com/someResource",
    data: { name: "David", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function(response) {
    // handle the response
});
```

The function which contains "handle the response" will be called by the system when the AJAX response is received from the server.  The `response` variable (or whatever you want to call that variable, the name doesn't matter) will contain whatever the server sent in return.  Which could be anything, really.

Comment: So really I don't even need `data:` in the request if all I want to do is take the data that I received from the server when I made the request. I just do it all in `.done((data received) = > {do stuff});`

Comment: @RyanTibbetts: If there's no data to send, then sure.  There are a variety of options to be used in the documentation, but very few of them are necessarily required for any given AJAX request.

Comment: I did not try this to see if this actually worked, I assume it does, however I used the on success way to handle data, Thanks for your help David, you also got me understanding the ajax request more as well.